Bounded linear map on a subspace of a normed vector space that cannot be continuously extended to the subspace's closure.

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of a normed vector space $V$. Suppose also that $W$ is a Banach space and $S: U \to W$ is a bounded linear map.
(a) Prove that there exists a unique continuous function $T: \overline{U} \to W$ such that $T|_U = S$.
(b) Prove that the function $T$ in part (a) is a bounded linear map from $\overline{U}$ to $W$ and $\|T\| = \|S\|$.
(c) Give an example to show that part (a) can fail if the assumption that $W$ is a Banach space is replaced by the assumption that $W$ is a normed vector space.

This is question 14 in section 6C of Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis by Axler. I did parts (a) and (b), but I have been stumped on part (c) all day.

Clearly $U$ must not be a Banach space, but the book only provides a couple of examples of normed vector spaces that are not Banach spaces.
I have been restricting my search to subspaces of the vector space of infinite sequences, but I have not been able to find any that fit the bill. This makes me think that I need to look in a completely different place, but I have no idea where.

It suffices to take $U$ to be any non-closed subspace of a normed vector space $V$, $W = U$, and $S$ to be the identity map $\text{id}_U : U \to U$. As an explicit example we can take $V = \ell^2(S)$ to be the $\ell^2$ space of an infinite set $S$ and $U$ to be the subspace of sequences with finite support (which is dense in $V$ and so not closed).
If $U$ is not closed then it is never possible to extend the identity map $\text{id}_U$ to a continuous map $T : \overline{U} \to U$. This is because we can apply part a) to the inclusion $U \hookrightarrow \overline{U}$, and it tells us that this inclusion uniquely extends to a continuous map $\overline{U} \to \overline{U}$, which must be $\text{id}_{\overline{U}}$. Any continuous extension of $\text{id}_U$ to a continuous map $T : \overline{U} \to U$ must, after composing with the inclusion $U \hookrightarrow \overline{U}$, also be a continuous extension of the inclusion, and so must agree with $\text{id}_{\overline{U}}$. If $U$ is not closed this means it cannot take values in $U$ only.
